# How to install mssql extension on hhvm?

Tags: php, hhvm

I try to use hhvm on debian wheezy, but have some problem. I use mssql with freetds in my application.

There are any idea how to install mssql on hhvm?

Thank you

Comment: I just install hhvm on debian wheezy, and I check function_exists("mssql_connect") and return false, I don't have any idea how to add extension for hhvm

Answer (score 1):

According to [HHVM's wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions), the `mssql` extension is not loaded by default in HHVM. It's probably not supported.

You could open an issue on GitHub and ask for the extension to be included, or you could try building and including it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

mssql extension is not implemented in HHVM.
Try: https://github.com/huzhiguang/hiphop_extension/tree/mssql

Comment: Hi. I have tried following the instructions in the github project linked above without success. Can it be made simpler? secondly, the free tds link in the steps is no longer available. Kindly help.